# Experimental strobelight duty cycle?

Tags: led, duty-cycle, strobelight

I am building an LED based low power strobe light. Currently it is running at 50% duty cycle, which is when I realised, it might not fully work, since if the light is on for half the time, the vibration I am trying to capture would have moved a lot within that time.

Does anyone have any ballpark figures of the duty cycle that strobe lights for physics experiments run at? I tried searching for it but could not get any solid figures (just unitless graphs which seem to suggest around 10%).

So do any of you guys have any idea?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what is the strobe light for? Are you trying to photograph some oscillation action?

Comment: Yes sure I probably shouldve said this earlier. It is to capture some guitar string vibrations in the range of ~80 to 1000hz.(that is it's first application. But I wanted to create a decent general purpose strobe light)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually pulse LEDs at currents significantly over their rated current as long as you keep the pulse short, and the duty cycle low enough. With low inductance paths between a storage capacitor and the LED, an LED's rise and fall times are nearly instantaneous, making pulse lengths on the order of microseconds entirely practical.

I recently helped out with [this kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/vela/vela-one-the-worlds-first-high-speed-led-flash), which generates flash pulses from 0.5 to 5 microseconds in duration by overdriving high powered LEDs by a factor of 20 from their rated values; long term testing showed some reduction in output, but no thermal or bondwire failures.

[This paper](http://elib.dlr.de/64324/1/mst075402_ledpiv_willert_2010.pdf) goes into some detail on testing LED overdriving for short pulses in high speed velocimetery experiments.

Regarding duty cycle, the important parameter is the total light delivered in a single exposure; when you shorten the duty cycle, you need to increase the light output proportionally. Overdriving helps with this, but results in reduced efficiency; doubling the current does not double the light output. You'll need to experiment to determine what LEDs you need and how far you can overdrive them (if that's the approach you take) to get sufficient lighting for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Typical LED duration is 0.1° up to maybe 2°, so divide that by 3.6 to get percent. The longer the pulse the more blurry and crappy the 'stop motion'.

LEDs are not particularly well suited for this kind of strobe application since the maximum current is quite limited out of consideration for damage to the chip. You need extreme energy in very brief pulses to add up to a decent average **power** in order to get decent visual brightness. Discharge flash tubes excel at that, but they have other inconveniences (high voltage, recovery time, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Typical strobe lights, such as those made by General Radio, have light durations on the order of a couple of microseconds while the flash rate is from 100 to 25000 per minute.  Therefore, if we take typical values such as 1 microsecond for the duration and 1000 flashes per minute for the rate, the duty cycle is only .00017.